# How to go about learning the android framework

Tags: android

I just started looking at the android framework and was wondering what was the best way going about getting good at it. I started with a text game and created a simple bubbleWrap game next. But am not sure if I'm going about it the right way now, so I thought I'd ask some of you more experienced Android people out here. Are there any courses online that would be beneficial? Any books that helped ya'll?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to learn developing Android applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211193/how-to-learn-developing-android-applications)

Comment: Oh, oops. Didn't see that, my bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I m listing some forums that may help you getting started with Android:

- http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html . Besides getting started, it also teaches to build a hello world app, demonstrates how to build menus and work with preferences, a nice content provider example and how to make a file browser. At last it demonstrates how to deploy your app onto a real device.
- http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/ This is one of my best recommendations. Some very nice demo projects are hosted on the site.
- http://smartandroidians.blogspot.com/ Nice tutorials by Nithin Warreir. The blog contains some code snippets that help during development of big projects. One can learn implementation of various tools of Android development easily here.
- http://www.anddev.org/ Anddev forum is pretty famous for having a large number of online users everytime. For any query you can easily post a question in this forum. Wait for the help that comes in just a few minutes.
- http://slideme.org/ Besides the Official Marketplace, this is another marketplace that hosts developer's applications. For registering as developer in the official marketplace, one needs to pay $25, here lies the advantage of joining SlideMe, it is free..!!

Also try two books for Android Application development:
Android 2 Application Development

> OReilly Android Application
>   Development and Wrox Professional
>   Android 2 Application Development

Hope that helps...

Comment: android.com has huge amounts on it too

Comment: •http://marakana.com is not available anymore :(

Answer (score 2):

I started out reading [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) to get the 10,000 foot view of the framework.  From there I bought [Pro Android 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430226595) in order to quickly learn about various Android subjects.  I don't necessarily need to know about all of these subjects now, but it helps to know about other options.  For instance, I don't need to use Content Providers right now, but they are a useful topic to be aware of if my app's requirements head in that direction.  After flipping through that book I took a look at some of the tutorials that related to my application.

I'm currently developing my application with great success, although I continually have to reference the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html). Answering questions on stackoverflow has also helped me quite a bit, because I often learn more about the framework in researching for responses.

Also, make an effort to read a Technical Article every day from [Developer Resources](http://developer.android.com/resources/index.html). Most of the articles are easy to follow, and they often cover issues you may not consider (such as the article on [Avoiding Memory Leaks](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)).

Answer (score 0):

I've just finished reading [Beginning Android 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430226293) and can recommend it over the Oreilly book, it is a lot more thorough and gives you virtually every topic you need to learn for Android development. The author is on stackoverflow as commonsware I believe too.

The best option is to get an O'Reilly Safari subscription, then you get a whole bookshelf of Android books for $20 a month.